# Removing class after X seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying this below code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $("button").hover(

            function() {
                $(this).addClass("active");
            },

            function() {
                $(this).removeClass("active");
            }
        );

    });
```

Comment: `setTimeout(...)`

Comment: What's your use case, what problem are you trying to solve? Because yes, this can – of course – be done as you describe, but I suspect there are better/alternative ways.

Comment: Well I'm adding a class on hover and want to remove it after x seconds. Trying below code but its not happening(using jquery3.21.1.min.js).

setTimeout(
function() {
$(this).removeClass("active");
},5000)

Comment: @DavidThomas - I myself have had countless use-cases for such a thing throughout the years (over a decade) and this is **such** a common thing to need so I wrote an extension just for that. see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Try this: http://plnkr.co/edit/Xlco44QPWvKEh1jb0gDf?p=preview

```
var button = $('button');

button.hover(
  function() {
    button.addClass('active');

    setTimeout(function() {
      button.removeClass('active');
    }, 3000);
  },
  function() {
    button.removeClass('active');
  }
);
```

From what you said in your previous comment below, you tried `setTimeout` and it didn't work because of the the way you used `this`. The value of `this` inside the timeout function wasn't the same as in your outer function, so jQuery didn't match your button element.

Better to define the button once as a variable, and reuse the variable, that use repeated jQuery selectors.

UPDATE: Here's a slightly more sophisticated version that keeps the `setTimeout` timers from piling up:

```
$(function() {
  var button = $('button');
  var timeout = 0;

  button.hover(
    function() {
      button.addClass('active');

      timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        button.removeClass('active');
        timeout = 0;
      }, 2000);
    },
    function() {
      button.removeClass('active');

      if (timeout) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = 0;
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: I tried this code and it worked for me. The only difference was to make it by declaring through variable. Thanks a lot. Cheers!!!

Answer (score -1):

I have created a *jQuery* **extention** just for that! This is extremely common in web development:

### [jQuery.addTempClass.js](https://gist.github.com/yairEO/d607ac7a53d2aa87aa7e67fe13b8f9d6)

```js
$.fn.addTempClass = function(tempClass, duration){
    if( !tempClass )
        return this;

    return this.each(function(){
        var $elm = $(this),
            timer;

        $elm.addClass(tempClass);

        // clear any timeout, if was any
        clearTimeout( $elm.data('timeout') )

        timer = setTimeout(function(){
            $elm.removeClass(tempClass).removeData('timeout');
        }, duration || 100);

        // set the timer on the element
        $elm.data('timeout', timer);
    });
};
```

### Usage example:

```
$(document.body).addTempClass('some_class', 2000)
```

---

You can include this script as a dependency file for your build system or simply copy-paste this piece of code somewhere in your code, just after *jQuery* has loaded, so it will be available everywhere afterwards.